# Пошаговая форма с переходом

Tags: javascript, jquery

подскажите пожалуйста, как можно реализовать следующий функционал.

Есть две формы, после того как пользователь заполнил  информацию в первой форме, он нажимает кнопку "далее", и показывается вторая форма, в которой он вводит информацию

Для наглядности пример на картинке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

!!! Нужно реализовать только переход к другой форме, без отправки

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62418712/javascript-for-showing-divs/62418902#62418902 ? Можно завернуть всю форму в такой блок.

Comment: Данное решение подходит, спасибо Вам большое!)